# Cassandra: Inconsistent data on reads (LOCAL_QUORUM)

Tags: cassandra-2.1

We're seeing inconsistent data while doing reads on cassandra. Here are the details:

It's is a wide column table. The columns can be added my multiple machines, and read by multiple machines. The time between writes and reads are in minutes, but sometimes can be in seconds. Writes happen every 2 minutes.

Now, while reading we're seeing the following cases of inconsistent reads:

- One column was added. If a read was done after the column was added (20 secs to 2 minutes after the write), Cassandra returns no data. As if the key doesn't exist. If the application retries, it gets the data.
- A few columns exist for a row key. And a new column 'n' was added. Again, a read happens a few minutes after the write. This time, only the latest column 'n' is returned. In this case the app doesn't know that the data is incomplete so it doesn't retry. If we manually retry, we see all the columns.
- A few columns exist for a row key. And a new column 'n' is added. When a read happens after the write, all columns but 'n' are returned.

Here's what we've verified:

- Both writes and reads are using 'LOCAL_QUORUM' consistency level.
- The replication is within local data center. No remote data center is involved in the read or write.
- During the inconsistent reads, none of the nodes are undergoing GC pauses
- There are no errors in cassandra logs
- Reads always happen after the writes.

A few other details:
Cassandra version: 2.1.9
DataStax java driver version: 2.1.10.2
Replication Factor: 3

We don't see this problem in lower environments. We have seen this happen once or twice last year, but since last few days it's happening quite frequently. On an average 2 inconsistent reads every minute.

Here's how the table definition looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE" (
  key text,
  sub_key text,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((key), sub_key)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='ALWAYS' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Please point us in the right direction. Thanks !

Comment: are u sure that the new entry does not have same (key + subkey) value as some old entry ?? ..in that case the data will be overwritten. Also are your nodes in   time synch ??  .

Comment: Hi Laxmikant. Yeah, we're sure that the new entry does not have the same (key + subKey). Another thing to mention is there are no deletes on this table. And yes, nodes are synced for time.

Comment: Have you find the reason? We are experiencing same situation with Cassandra 3.0.